AWS Neptune slow query logs are not captured
I have set neptune neptune_enable_slow_query_log flag to debug.
with neptune_slow_query_log_threshold set to 5000.
slowquery logs link are seen in cloudwatch logs section in the configuration section of Neptune.
But when I click the link to view the logs, I get the below error :
"There was an error filtering log events.
The specified log group does not exist."
I have rebooted neptune instance after the parameter group changes.
Any suggestions, how can I view the slow logs.

Are you sending queries to Neptune that take longer than 5 seconds to execute?

yes. I am sending query longer than 5 seconds. I tried decreasing the threshold as well, but it did not help.

And you're using a Neptune Engine version >= 1.2.1.0?

yes, Great point and it was working with 1.2 and not working with 1.3. Thanks

If every other thing is set up correctly. The only reason should be that there is no IAM role attached to the DB, Or the IAM role does not have the permissions for CloudWatch.

This may not be entirely relevant.  Neptune uses the RDS control plane and a RDS Service Linked Role for pushing to CloudWatch.  So to the point above, you need to make sure the RDS Service Linked Role is created in your account.

I have faced scenarios where my user has limited access due to which RDS service linked role was created however somehow it was unable to perform the required tasks. Same happened with my DMS task.
